# SFINAE works explicitly but not implicitly

Tags: c++, c++11, sfinae

I'm working with multiple different versions of a library that have different sets of enums defined, and I'm trying to switch at compile-time based on whether or not different values exist. I'm using the `decltype()` vs `...` trick:

```
enum E {
    FOO = 0,
    BAR
};

template <typename U>
inline void add_FOO(std::vector<U>& v, decltype(U::FOO)* ) {
    std::cout << "YES\n";
}

template <typename U>
inline void add_FOO(std::vector<U>& v, ... ) {
    std::cout << "NO\n";
}
```

But when I try to use it:

```
std::vector<E> v;
add_FOO(v, nullptr);      // prints NO
add_FOO<E>(v, nullptr);   // prints YES
```

Why the difference? `U` should get deduced as `E`, so why do I need to specify it explicitly? I'm compiling on gcc 4.7.2.

Comment: Tested with g++ 4.9.2 and clang++ 3.6.0 I get YES twice, so I'm guessing that you have a compiler bug. What compiler are you using?

Comment: @rodrigo sigh. 4.7.2.

Comment: 4.8 also has NO/YES, so this looks like something that's been fixed in 4.9

Comment: Hmm, `(E*) nullptr` works. Interesting. My guess is that GCC 4.7/8 sees that `nullptr_t` is not a pointer type and called it a substitution failure right there, without looking at whether `U` is in a deducible context or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a GCC bug to me. There are plenty of workarounds. For example:

```
template <typename U>
inline auto add_FOO(std::vector<U>& v, int) -> decltype(U::FOO, void()) {
    std::cout << "YES\n";
}

template <typename U>
inline void add_FOO(std::vector<U>& v, ... ) {
    std::cout << "NO\n";
}

add_FOO(v, 0);
```

or

```
template <typename U, decltype(U::FOO)* = nullptr>
inline void add_FOO(std::vector<U>& v, int) {
    std::cout << "YES\n";
}

template <typename U>
inline void add_FOO(std::vector<U>& v, ... ) {
    std::cout << "NO\n";
}

add_FOO(v, 0);
```

Comment: Or, surprisingly enough, wrapping `decltype(U::FOO)*` into a non-deduced context - `template<class T> struct identity{ using type = T; }; template<class T> using non_deduced = typename identity<T>::type;` and use `non_deduced<decltype(U::FOO)*>`, which makes me think that GCC 4.7 is for whatever reason attempting to deduce U from the second parameter.

Comment: Yeah all three of those work, thanks. I guess I just need to upgrade. Glad they have it already fixed at least.